# Rails Oracle enhanced adapter ignores pool size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4

I use 3 thin servers (behind an Nginx proxy) for my productive Rails app. Each of the thin servers produces 5 connections to the database. So my app has 15 connections in total. My Oracle admin complains that I use too many connections.

I do not know how to reduce the number of connections. I tried `pool: 2` in `database.yml`, and restarted all thin servers, but my app still produces 15 connections. It seems that the `pool` setting is not used at all.

Of course, I could reduce the number of thin server, but I would like to know how to use `pool`.

I have another Rails app using PostgreSQL. Here, this parameter works as expected.

I use Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1

```
production:
    adapter: oracle_enhanced
    database: "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx)(PORT=12345)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=yyy)))"
    pool: 2
    username: ORACLE_USER
    password: ORACLE_PASSWORD
```

Comment: You would answer to this question here, as well as on the github. And accept own answer :) . Btw. (quoting github answer) "after reboot DB" - is it really DB reboot issue, not rails app reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to open issue at https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced - the maintainers check that more often.

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot of the database server, everything works as expected ...